# TCP. Физический разрыв связи

Tags: tcp

Как ведет себя TCP при физическом разрыве связи? Интересует сценарий когда один из узлов отправляет пакет, но он не дошел, так как был дисконнект временный (пинг не постоянный) и что в этом случае происходит, как отправляющий узел узнает что пакет его не дошел? У него есть таймаут, по истечению которого он повторно отправляет этот же пакет или просто разрывает связь?

Comment: Таймауты есть, но как минимум линукс вроде бы позволяет их настроить https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907527

Comment: «как отправляющий узел узнает» — по отсутствию ответа ACK от получателя. Будет повторно отправлять пакет до тех пор, пока не получит ACK или не случится таймаут (если таймауты не отключены)

Comment: "до тех пор, пока не получит ACK или не случится таймаут": тое есть 2 тайм-аута - один на повторную отправку, а другой на получение АСК от получателя?